# Adding page number in every page of pdf using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.create("Text");
  var body = doc.getBody();
  doc.addHeader().appendParagraph("This is a header");
  body.appendParagraph('text');
  function addTable("dynamicTable parameters",doc);
  var footer = doc.addFooter();
  var table = footer.appendTable();
  var tr = table.appendTableRow();
  var count = 1;
  var td = tr.appendTableCell();
  td.appendParagraph('this is a document.');
  td.setWidth(203);

  var td1 = tr.appendTableCell();
  td1.setWidth(260);
  var table1x2 = td1.appendTable();
  var tr1x2 = table1x2.appendTableRow();
  tr1x2.appendTableCell("Document Type")
  .appendParagraph("").appendText("Notes");
  tr1x2.appendTableCell("Author")
  .appendParagraph("").appendText("Text");

  var table1x4 = td1.appendTable();
  var tr1x4 = table1x4.appendTableRow();
  tr1x4.appendTableCell("Document No.")
  .appendParagraph("").appendText(count++);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT"+5.5, "dd-MM-yyyy");

  tr1x4.appendTableCell("Date")
  .appendParagraph("").appendText(date);
  tr1x4.appendTableCell("Volume No.");
  tr1x4.appendTableCell("Page No.")
  .appendParagraph("").appendText(PageNo);
```

The above is sample code I am using to generate footer in every page of pdf.I am trying to add page no in the last code shown above. But unable to increment it dynamically. Is there a way I can display the current page in the page No. column.Kindly let me know if there is any other way I can add page no while converting doc to pdf or any work around is also accepted.

Comment: The code you've included in your question doesn't show how it progresses  between pages, nor how `PageNo` is defined, so I'm not sure this will work for you. However, you should be able to just use `.appendText(PageNo++)` to post-increment the variable after appending it to the "Page No." cell. If you're looking for automatic page numbering... it's not supported. You've mentioned pdf, and tagged your question pdf, probably because the program you're working on is to produce a pdf. However, since this question does not actually concern pdf files, you should remove that tag.

Comment: Is there any way to automatically update the Page No?. Because the addFooter() function creates footer in every page dynamically but there is no option to increment page no. @Mogsdad

Comment: Already answered... no.